# Searching Message For Key Words In Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

When sending an email, I want to search the recipients of the email as well as the email body for certain key works, and if found, pop up a message to confirm sending.

I am able to get a pop up when the user hits the send key. I'm unable to access the recipient or message objects to search them.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim xPrompt As String
Dim xOkOrCancel As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xPrompt = "Do you want to continue sending the email?"
xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbOKCancel)
If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

I added the following code to try to see the recipient, but it is not returning anything.

```
Set myAddressEntry = myRecipient.AddressEntry
xPrompt = Trim(myAddressEntry) 
xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbOKCancel)
```

Comment: Look at the Item object being passed in as a parameter to the Application_ItemSend function. It should be of type [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to) which has the property To for the recipients

Comment: vb.net and vba are 2 entirely different languages. Set is not supported in vb.net. Which language are you coding in?

Comment: I don't see any code searching anything for keywords. Please post the code that shows the search.

Comment: Mary, I am using VBA, and you are correct...I'm not doing any searches yet. I first need to make sure I am able to access the recipient as well as the message in outlook. That is the reason for my second snipet of code...Im just trying to verify that Im accessing the info contained on the email I am about to send...but nothing appears in the msgbox above.

Comment: Jazakari... I modified my code above to display the ITEM object being passed in, and when I did, it displayed the subject line of my email, not the recipient. Im only a casual VBA user, so Im researching how to interact with the other properties of the mailitem. If anyone could post the correct syntax using mailitem to retrieve the recipients of the email along with the body of the email, It would be very much appreciated. Ill keep trying on this end too.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a COM object to a function that expects a string. More than that, you don't need the `Recipient.AddressEntry` property, just work with the Recipient object since it is resolved.

```
xPrompt = Trim(myRecipient.Name)
```

I assume you correctly initialize the `myRecipient` object from the `Item.Recipients` collection.